# mind-boggling/curious historical facts that will inspire and attract young people

Tags: teaching

I am trying to compile a list of mind-boggling/curious  historical facts in mathematics that will inspire and attract young people (9–11 years old) to the discipline of Mathematics. Do you have one fact to share? Multidisciplinary historical facts are welcome!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26596/do-you-know-a-mind-boggling-curious-historical-facts-that-will-inspire-and-attra

Comment: Specific mention of mathematics is missing from this article but there is plenty of related inspiration here. https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.adi8737

Comment: "attract young people (9–11 years old) to the discipline of Mathematics" : How about this mind-boggling fact: $9-11=-2$ ?